# Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/var/www/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream:

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

`Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/var/www/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Read-only file system in /var/www/bootstrap/compiled.php:8699`

I've been working on a Laravel project for a few weeks and all of the sudden this error appears.  What's causing this?

I've already run:

`chmod 777 app/storage`

I ran it before beginning on the project and ran it again and it doesn't make any difference.

What is the problem here?

Comment: /var/www/ looks to be mount mounted as read only.

What is the output when run "cat /proc/mounts" in the terminal?

Comment: /dev/simfs / simfs rw,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,mode=755,gid=501 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=52432k,mode=755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0

I think it may be an issue with the hosting service

Comment: Probably. If you have admin rights try to restart the server.

Comment: I've tried to reboot through the portal to no avail.  I've contacted support.

Comment: Once you have fixed your issue please answer your question yourself so we can know what was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

While you are in it's directory, just do this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 vendor storage
echo "umask 000" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```